# Evince does not see my search string. But why not?

Tags: fonts, pdf, search, evince, adobe-acrobat

I have got a number of pdf documents (bank account statements), where I regularly need to search for certain kinds of transaction by keyword. Recently I observed that with Acrobat 9 (a very old version) I can do so, however, with current Evince 3.10.3 searching does not work.

I looked up the document properties and found that those pdf documents have two fonts **ArialMT** and **Arial BoldMT**. After I installed `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` I noticed that Acrobat leaves the fonts, whereas Evince replaces them by **DejaVu Sans** (`/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSans.ttf`)  and 
**Arial Negrata** (`/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/Arial_Bold.ttf`), respectively.

So, even if the pdf documents, when opened in Evince, have got two well-defined fonts, my search by keyword results in "not found".

I would like to understand:

1. why Evince cannot find what Acrobat can find, and
2. if that is a matter of configuration or an an Evince bug.

Comment: Are you still having this problem? Do you have a link to a sample `pdf`?

Comment: Related: [PDF font falls back to DejaVu Sans, need a monospace replacement](https://askubuntu.com/q/773854/567307)