# PDF font falls back to DejaVu Sans, need a monospace replacement

Tags: 16.04, fonts, pdf, evince

I have a PDF that features code fragments and it references `Courier Std` (which is not available on my system and I am not planning to buy it either). The problem is that in the `Evince Document Viewer` (3.18.2) this font is replaced by `DejaVu Sans`, which is not a `monospace` font and code that is note set in a monospace font is just hard to read. (the idiosyncratic kerning adjustment just makes it even harder).

I have installed the `msttcorefonts` in the hope that it might help, it does not. How can replace DejaVu Sans with a monospace font?

[image]

UPDATE: If I load the PDF in Firefox, the font gets correctly replaced by a monospace font.

Answer (score 1):

This issue should be [patched](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fontconfig/+bug/1824260) in the next version of Ubuntu (21.04). There is also an upstream fontconfig merge request [#128](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/fontconfig/fontconfig/-/merge_requests/128) pending.

---

In the meantime, the following steps should help address some PDF font substitution problems:

- Install `fonts-urw-base35`.
- Create the file `~/.config/fontconfig/conf.d/10-pdf-aliases.conf` with the following contents:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "/etc/fonts/conf.d/fonts.dtd">
  <fontconfig>

  <alias binding="same">
    <family>CourierStd</family>
    <accept>
    <family>Courier</family>
    </accept>
  </alias>

  <alias>
    <family>CourierStd</family>
    <default><family>monospace</family></default>
  </alias>

  </fontconfig>
  ```

  Then run `fc-cache` (may not be necessary).

  You can add other font aliases to the file as needed.

See also:

- [wrong letter positioning and font in PDF form](https://askubuntu.com/q/1031235/567307)