# wrong letter positioning and font in PDF form

Tags: fonts, pdf, poppler

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and filling out the [SS-5 Social Security Administration form](https://www.ssa.gov/forms/ss-5.pdf). However, some of the letters are wrongly positioned.

Evince 3.28.2-1:

[image: evince screenshot (has kerning issues)]

Okular 1.3.3 (Ubuntu version 4:17.12.3-0ubuntu1):

[image: Okular screenshot (has kerning issues)]

xpdf 3.04-7:

[image: xpdf screenshot (has kerning issues)]

mudpdf 1.12.0:

[image: mupdf screenshot (no kerning issues)]

The built-in PDF reader for Firefox 59.0.2:

[image: firefox screenshot (no kerning issues)]

The built-in PDF reader for Chromium 65.0.3325.181:

[image: chromium screenshot (no kerning issues)]

Here is the output of `pdffonts`:

```
$ pdffonts ss-5.pdf
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
IHPIKC+ArialMT                       CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    824  0
ArialMT                              TrueType          WinAnsi          no  no  no     826  0
Arial-BoldMT                         TrueType          WinAnsi          no  no  no     828  0
CourierStd                           Type 1            WinAnsi          no  no  no     145  0
Helvetica                            Type 1            WinAnsi          no  no  no     197  0
MyriadPro-Regular                    Type 1            WinAnsi          no  no  no     198  0
ZapfDingbats                         Type 1            ZapfDingbats     no  no  no     199  0
```

I have already installed the `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` and `poppler-data` packages.

Here are my questions:

- Can I change the font used for filling in the cells of the form?

  It seems like Evince and xpdf are using a variable-width font when they should be using a monospaced font, and maybe this is causing the positioning problem.
- If I were to file a bug report, should I file it as a poppler issue, a fontconfig issue, or somewhere else?

Update: bug reports:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fontconfig/+bug/1824260
- https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/evince/issues/1127
- https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/poppler/poppler/issues/753

Edit: The workaround from @xiota is perfectly functional. However, this is still a bug in poppler, because when the PDF viewer substitutes a different font due to the original not being embedded, the spacing in the XFA form should match the *substituted font*, not the original font. There is a [pull request](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/poppler/poppler/-/merge_requests/61) to fix this that is currently in progress. Poppler developer Tobias Deiminger (@haxtibal) described the approach in [a different bug report](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/poppler/poppler/-/issues/694):

> The strategy there is, if a font is not embedded, gather and use metrics from
> the actual substitute font instead of metrics from PDF font descriptor or
> hardcoded ones.

Comment: I have the same issue with evince 3.32 but I am on Arch Linux. I think it is a font substitution problem too. You can try play with `/etc/fonts/conf.d/` files

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This issue should be [patched](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fontconfig/+bug/1824260) in the next version of Ubuntu (21.04). There is also an upstream fontconfig merge request [#128](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/fontconfig/fontconfig/-/merge_requests/128) pending.

---

**The problem you are observing is caused by incorrect font substitution.** On my computer, CourierStd and ZapfDingbats are replaced with Ubuntu. That will obviously not render properly.

[image: pdf font properties]

To correct this:

- Install `fonts-urw-base35`. This should correct the Dingbats and most other pdf font substitutions. However, CourierStd substitution is not fixed because it is not in the config files.
- To correct CourierStd, create the file `~/.config/fontconfig/conf.d/10-pdf-aliases.conf` with the following contents:

  ```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "/etc/fonts/conf.d/fonts.dtd">
    <fontconfig>

    <alias binding="same">
      <family>Courier Std</family>
      <accept>
      <family>Courier</family>
      </accept>
    </alias>

    <alias>
      <family>Courier Std</family>
      <default><family>monospace</family></default>
    </alias>

    </fontconfig>
  ```

  Then run `fc-cache` (may not be necessary).

  You can add other font aliases to the file as needed.

See also:

- [PDF font falls back to DejaVu Sans, need a monospace replacement](https://askubuntu.com/questions/773854/)

Comment: Great, it works! I also suggested your fix [here https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/fonts-meta-extended-lt/] (a package that I use, successor of *famous* infinality bohoomil patches) and they appreciated it!