# Incorrect font spacing to fill PDF form

Tags: fonts, pdf, evince, emulation, poppler

I am filling out this PDF form, [IRS Form 1040](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f1040.pdf), in evince 3.36.7 on Ubuntu 20.04 and having a problem that the numbers I input are not aligned correctly with the background bars. Please see this screenshot: [image: Form 1040, DejaVu]
In the box filled by `123456789`, the correct rendering should look like `123|45|6789`, but `5` is almost pushed out to the right of the second vertical bar. The spacing between the numbers are much wider than the form creator intended.

It looks that `Helvetica LT Std Bold` font is assigned to this box, but I don't have this font. Ubuntu substituted it with `DejaVu Sans Bold`.

I installed MS Core Fonts and changed the substitution with `Arial Bold` by editing `fonts.conf` file. However, the spacing did not change. (Screenshot not shown.)

I also tried filling and rendering the form in firefox, chrome, and okular, but they had the same spacing problem.

I think this problem have the same root as the issue reported in these posts.

- [wrong letter positioning and font in PDF form](https://askubuntu.com/q/1031235/148291)
- [Fonts rendered with broken kerning](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/poppler/poppler/-/issues/694)

The issue there has not been resolved for a several years, and it looks difficult to resolve it.

I would like to know any workarounds for this particular PDF form. Is it possible to specify substitution font size (to compensate the too-wide spacing)? Is there a PDF viewer that works? Should I buy the font?

Do Windows and Mac not have this problem? (If so why?  Isn't this essentially a problem of fonts? I guess `Helvetica LT` may not be on so many Windows or Mac computers.) If they work, does `wine` or `virtualbox` work?

---

*Edit*

The fonts used in the PDF are as following. Among them, the fonts for the input fields are `Zapf Dingbats`, `Helvetica`, and `Helvetica LT Std Bold`. I believe the numbers in question is `Helvetica LT Std Bold`.

```
$ pdffonts f1040_ssn_sample.pdf 
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
WVBKSB+UniversalStd-NewswithCommPi   CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes   1193  0
XULQGZ+ZapfDingbatsStd               CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes   1198  0
TGPSCH+HelveticaNeueLTStd-Roman      Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no    1200  0
ZHOHIV+HelveticaNeueLTStd-BlkCn      Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no    1202  0
XEPVGZ+HelveticaNeueLTStd-BdOu       Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no    1204  0
XEPVGZ+HelveticaNeueLTStd-Blk        Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no    1206  0
CEYUYP+ITCFranklinGothicStd-Demi     Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no    1208  0
UXBDQF+HelveticaNeueLTStd-Bd         Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no    1210  0
UXBDQF+HelveticaNeueLTStd-BdCn       Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no    1212  0
ATBIWT+HelveticaNeueLTStd-It         Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no    1214  0
Helvetica                            Type 1            WinAnsi          no  no  no     143  0
HelveticaLTStd-Bold                  Type 1            WinAnsi          no  no  no     144  0
ZapfDingbats                         Type 1            ZapfDingbats     no  no  no    1114  0
ZHOHIV+AdobePiStd                    CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes     69  0
```

Answer (score 3):

A very similar issue was found to be a fontconfig bug, and was fixed in [Ubuntu 21.04](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fontconfig/2.13.1-4.2ubuntu2) and also [upstream](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/fontconfig/fontconfig/-/commit/d9c99340).

So possibly, on 20.04, it's sufficient to open `/etc/fonts/conf.avail/45-latin.conf` for editing and add this snippet:

```
<alias>
    <family>Courier Std</family>
    <default><family>monospace</family></default>
</alias>
```

Comment: Thank you, but this form does not use Courier. I edited my question and added the full list of fonts in used in the PDF.

Comment: @norio: Sorry, I didn't read the question carefully enough. But with that said it ought to be some replacement font available which could be specified via fontconfig. Can't tell which one, though.

Comment: I tried replacing Helvetica LT with Arial and also with Nimbus Sans, but neither of them worked. I learned that Helvetica is metric-compatible with Arial and Nimbus Sans, and I believe Helvetica LT is essentially the same as Helvetica. So, it looks there is something more than missing-font in this problem. I am suspecting that the social security number box of Form 1040 has a font alignment or spacing specification that is not properly handled by evince or its back-end rendering engine.

Answer (score 2):

One option that *might* work for you is to grab a copy of the Helvetica `.dfont` file, convert it to a `.ttf`, and copy it to your fonts directory.

The gist goes like this:

1. Install [fondu](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/fondu)

   ```
   sudo apt install fondu
   ```
2. Download the Helvetica.dfont file [from this helpful GitHub repository](https://github.com/foliojs/pdfkit/tree/master/demo/fonts)
3. Convert the font:

   ```
   fondu Helvetica.dfont
   ```
4. Open the resulting `.ttf` using the *FontViewer* application. This is easiest by double-clicking the font file in Nautilus.
5. Click the “Install” button in the upper-right corner

Hopefully this will give you a better-spaced font.