# How to redefine font substitution?

Tags: fonts, configuration, pdf

I would like to have `HelveticaLTStd-Bold` substituted with `LiberationSans-Bold` font. It is already installed in many places:

[image]

but `DejaVu Sans` is chosen instead:

```
paul@desktop:~$ fc-match "HelveticaLTStd-Bold"
DejaVuSans.ttf: "DejaVu Sans" "Book"
```

I followed the advice from [PDF font falls back to DejaVu Sans, need a monospace replacement](https://askubuntu.com/questions/773854/pdf-font-falls-back-to-dejavu-sans-need-a-monospace-replacement), but it didn't work. What is the solution?

---

I use Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS x86_64. I checked that `fonts-urw-base35` is installed. I created `~/.config/fontconfig/conf.d/10-pdf-aliases.conf` file with this contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "/etc/fonts/conf.d/fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>

<alias binding="same">
<family>CourierStd</family>
<accept>
<family>Courier</family>
</accept>
</alias>

<alias>
<family>CourierStd</family>
<default><family>monospace</family></default>
</alias>

</fontconfig>
```

I've run `fc-cache` and I'm still getting:

```
paul@desktop:~$ fc-match "HelveticaLTStd-Bold"
DejaVuSans.ttf: "DejaVu Sans" "Book"
```

---

I didn't notice a different font name in that configuration file. I edited it, and it solves my problem with Document Viewer. Unfortunately, Okular (installed with Flatpak) still uses `DejaVu Sans` and produces this misformed kerning:

[image]

Here are the fonts used in this document:

[image]

Comment: Which Ubuntu version do you use? Can you please edit your question and show us how exactly you applied the advice from the other question?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I added the details you requested.

Comment: Can you provide a link to a PDF that demonstrates the issue?  What program generated it? (Wondering whether HelveticaLTStd needs to be added to default config files, like CourierStd was.)

Comment: @xiota I added more info. Let me know if you still need the PDF - I would have to remove a few fields.

Comment: Since the *Helvetica LT Std* font is used in some official American form, @xiota seems to have been right about his suspicion. OTOH, unlike Courier Std (which is a monospace font) this one is sans-serif. And preferring Liberation Sans over DejaVu Sans is merely a matter of personal preferences, isn't it? So there does not seem to be a need to propose a change to the default config files in this case.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson *preferring Liberation Sans over DejaVu Sans is merely a matter of personal preferences* - I don't care specifically about Liberation Sans, I just want to have a right kerning with whatever font can accomplish that. DejaVu doesn't.

Comment: I found a blank W9 form that demonstrates the issue.  The PDF would be needed to open up an issue so that the upstream project can update the default font configs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the other question helped deal with the `Courier Std` font while awaiting a fix upstream.

To start with, try replacing this section:

```
<alias binding="same">
<family>CourierStd</family>
<accept>
<family>Courier</family>
</accept>
</alias>
```

with:

```
<alias binding="same">
<family>HelveticaLTStd</family>
<accept>
<family>Liberation Sans</family>
</accept>
</alias>
```

Result on my machine:

```
$ fc-match "HelveticaLTStd: bold"
LiberationSans-Bold.ttf: "Liberation Sans" "Bold"
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how to handle the Flatpak (Okular) issue?

Comment: @PaulJurczak: No. Probably the Flatpak font configuration is sandboxed, as is the case with snaps. For some snaps I know how handle it.

Comment: Merge request to update configs: [fontconfig/282](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/fontconfig/fontconfig/-/merge_requests/282)